# Missing or invalid themes

Tags: 8

I created 2 custom themes a while ago and I deleted them since I don't need them anymore.

Although I deleted all the files, I am still getting this error.

> Missing or invalid themes
> The following themes are marked as installed in the core.extension configuration, but they are missing.

Is there a way to avoid this error message?

Answer (score 3):

You need to **uninstall** modules and themes before removing the files.

To fix:

1. Restore the deleted themes (if you don’t have them, create stub themes with the same machine names and a single .info.yml file each describing them as a theme)
2. Uninstall the themes using the UI
3. Remove the files again

The alternative is manually editing the active configuration, which is potentially much more messy.

Comment: I recreated the folders and info.yml files with exact same names and they are not displaying on the appearance menu. Do you know why?

Comment: you probably need to clear the cache

Answer (score 1):

If the theme is not there anymore and you cannot put the files back, you can use drush to force uninstall it (replace MYTHEME with the name of your theme).

```
drush eval "\$theme_data = \Drupal::config('core.extension')->get('theme'); unset(\$theme_data['MYTHEME']); \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('core.extension')->set('theme', \$theme_data)->save();"

drush php-eval "\Drupal::keyValue('config.entity.key_store.block')->delete('theme:MYTHEME');"

drush cr
```